# Is there a way to pass formulas for lm from one vector and get set of R2 in another vector (without using loop)?

Tags: r, lm

I'd like to check R2 in lm for different formulas on the same dataset.
I don't want to use loop, but pass formulas from one vector and get set of R2 in another vector.

I tried with the below code.

```
data(mtcars)
formulas <- paste("mpg~",colnames(mtcars[2:11]))
R_square <- summary(lm(data=mtcars,formulas))$r.squared
```

I expected R_square vector to contain as many values as formulas vector, but it has only one value.
It works as if it built only one model for the first formula.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like:

```
R_square <- sapply(formulas, 
                   function(x) summary(lm(x, data = mtcars))$r.squared)

> R_square
 mpg~ cyl mpg~ disp   mpg~ hp mpg~ drat   mpg~ wt mpg~ qsec   mpg~ vs 
0.7261800 0.7183433 0.6024373 0.4639952 0.7528328 0.1752963 0.4409477 
  mpg~ am mpg~ gear mpg~ carb 
0.3597989 0.2306734 0.3035184
```

Comment: That did the job, thank You!
I'm wondering if it's more efficient way of getting the results than coding it in a loop. As far as I know R prefers vectorized operations than loops and that is the reason I was looking for that solution.